# No IP address at boot

Tags: centos, networking, ip

The wifi interface IP address is not set at boot:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7d:7b:ce:ff:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.25.111/24 brd 192.168.25.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::67d:7bff:fece:ffb6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:6d:57:a0:ac:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Config file:

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-DKT 
HWADDR=44:6D:57:A0:AC:07
TYPE=Wireless
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.1.1.1
PREFIX=16
GATEWAY=192.168.25.1
DNS1=127.0.0.1
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="DKT"
UUID=57e247c1-b430-43e2-a204-4fe603a8d7a2
DEVICE="wlp2s0"
ONBOOT=yes
ESSID="DKT"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Log:

```
# systemctl -l status network.service
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-11-25 19:29:38 UTC; 13min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1109 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 25 19:29:35 sg.dkt systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Nov 25 19:29:37 sg.dkt network[1109]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt network[1109]: Bringing up interface DKT:  [FAILED]
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt network[1109]: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Nov 25 19:29:38 sg.dkt systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

I can set the IP address manually:

```
# ip addr add 10.1.1.1/16 dev wlp2s0
# ip addr show dev wlp2s0
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:6d:57:a0:ac:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.1/16 scope global wlp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How does `GATEWAY=192.168.25.1` make sense with your IP being `10.1.1.1/16`?  You're obviously skipping a step in your logic but I can't guess what you're actually trying to do with this.

Comment: You can add an ip address to an interface at any time, but bringing it up is another matter, see if you can bring the interface up manually by giving the following command: `ip link set dev wlp2s0 up`

Comment: @ojs It is already up at boot although the network service log says otherwise. Check the first output from `ip address show`. The only thing missing is the IP

Comment: @Julie: That is another matter. Would it prevent the IP address setting?

Comment: I can't test it but I suspect it might.

Comment: @Julie Just rebooted with `GATEWAY=10.1.1.1` and it makes no difference to the IP problem.

Comment: Of course.  How can it be its own gateway?

Comment: We can not guess your network layout but you must define (know) what network your adapter is connecting to to configure it on the computer.